# Click multiple divs with same class name using for loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to click on multiple div with same class name. Parse the HTML page, extract some information and get back to same page.
On this [page](https://blinkit.com/cn/masala-oil-more/whole-spices/cid/1557/930).

1. Select item and extract relevant information
2. Get back to same [page](https://blinkit.com/cn/masala-oil-more/whole-spices/cid/1557/930)
3. Click on next item.

This works perfectly outside the for loop.

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="product__wrapper"][1]'))).click()
```

But when I use the above command inside my loop. It throws error InvalidSelectorException

```
for i in range(1,len(all_profile_url)):
        
        
        WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="product__wrapper"][{i}]'))).click()
        time.sleep(10)
        wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,1000)')
        
        page_source = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

        info_div = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductInfoCard__Breadcrumb-sc-113r60q-4 cfIqZP')

        info_block = info_div.find_all('a')
        try:
            info_category = info_block[1].get_text().strip()
        except IndexError:
            info_category ="Null"
        wd.back()
        time.sleep(5)
```

WHAT I want to extract from each page using the code below

```
page_source = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

info_div = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductInfoCard__Breadcrumb-sc-113r60q-4 cfIqZP')

info_block = info_div.find_all('a')
try:
    info_category = info_block[1].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_category ="Null"

try:
    info_sub_category = info_block[2].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_sub_category='Null'

try:
    info_product_name = info_div.find_all('span')[0].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_product_name='null'


# Extract Brand name
info_div_1 = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductInfoCard__BrandContainer-sc-113r60q-9 exyKqL')
try:
    info_brand = info_div_1.find_all('a')[0].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_brand='null'


# Extract details for rest of the page
info_div_2 = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductDetails__RemoveMaxHeight-sc-z5f4ag-3 fOPLcr')
info_block_2 = info_div_2.find_all('div', class_='ProductAttribute__ProductAttributesDescription-sc-dyoysr-2 lnLDYa')
try:
    info_shelf_life = info_block_2[0].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_shelf_life = 'null'

try:
    info_country_of_origin = info_block_2[3].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_country_of_origin='null'

try:
    info_weight = info_block_2[9].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_weight ='null'

try:
    info_expiry_date = info_block_2[7].get_text().strip()
except IndexError:
    info_expiry_date='null'
# Extract MRP and price
# Extract MRP and price
info_div_3 = page_source.find('div', class_='ProductVariants__VariantDetailsContainer-sc-1unev4j-7 fvkqJd')
info_block_3 = info_div_3.find_all('div', class_='ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9 jjiIua')
info_price_raw = info_block_3[0].get_text().strip()
info_price = info_block_3[0].get_text().strip()[1:3]
info_MRP = info_price_raw[-2:]
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could minify your example?

Comment: @dosas Edited above

Comment: I would suggest you to get the link of all items at once and then visit the url one by one

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar That's exactly what I did in my first attempt. Using wd.get(all_profile_url[i]). But loop failed exactly on .get() command after first few iterations. Then I took the longer route and restarted webdriver in every loop. But that also failed randomly on wd.get() command

Comment: okay tell me what do you need from every card in the page?

Comment: I have coded that part I'll include that above in EDIT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246177/discussion-between-yash-agarwal-and-himanshu-poddar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need to use BeautifulSoup to parse the data. Selenium has methods that will be sufficient for our use case.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
    

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
s = Service(chrome_path)
url = 'https://blinkit.com/cn/masala-oil-more/whole-spices/cid/1557/930'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)

click_location_tooltip = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[@data-test-id='address-correct-btn']")
click_location_tooltip.click()

cards_elements_list = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@data-test-id='plp-product']")
card_link_list = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in cards_elements_list]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['info_category','info_sub_category','info_product_name','info_brand','info_shelf_life','info_country_of_origin','info_weight','info_expiry_date','price','mrp'])

for url in card_link_list:
  driver.get(url)
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ProductInfoCard__BreadcrumbLink-sc-113r60q-5')))
  except TimeoutException:
      print(url + ' cannot be loaded')
      continue
  bread_crumb_links = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[@class='ProductInfoCard__BreadcrumbLink-sc-113r60q-5 hRvdxN']")
  info_category = bread_crumb_links[1].text.strip()
  info_sub_category = bread_crumb_links[2].text.strip()

  product_name = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//span[@class='ProductInfoCard__BreadcrumbProductName-sc-113r60q-6 lhxiqc']")
  info_product_name = product_name.text

  brand_name = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='ProductInfoCard__BrandContainer-sc-113r60q-9 exyKqL']")
  info_brand = brand_name.text

  product_details = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[@class='ProductAttribute__ProductAttributesDescription-sc-dyoysr-2 lnLDYa']")
  info_shelf_life = product_details[0].text.strip()
  info_country_of_origin = product_details[1].text.strip()
  info_weight = product_details[7].text.strip()
  info_expiry_date = product_details[5].text.strip()

  div_containing_radio = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__RadioButtonInner')]//ancestor::div[starts-with(@class, 'ProductVariants__VariantCard')]")

  price_mrp_div = div_containing_radio.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".ProductVariants__PriceContainer-sc-1unev4j-9.jjiIua")
  mrp_price_list = price_mrp_div.text.split("₹")
  price = mrp_price_list[1]
  mrp = ''
  if(len(mrp_price_list) > 2):
    mrp = mrp_price_list[2]

  data_dict = {'info_category' : info_category, 'info_sub_category' : info_sub_category, 'info_product_name' : info_product_name, 'info_brand' : info_brand, 'info_shelf_life' : info_shelf_life, 'info_country_of_origin': info_country_of_origin, 'info_weight' : info_weight, 'info_expiry_date' : info_expiry_date , 'price' : price, 'mrp' : mrp}
  df_dict = pd.DataFrame([data_dict])
  df = pd.concat([df, df_dict])
```

Output :

[image]

**P.S :** Please note that `product_details` is not exactly a structured element and just text which we need to parse using regex if want to generalize it for all urls, hence you will have to do some exceptional handling while indexing the list `product_details` which you have done in your code.

Comment: Webdrivers  act weird sometimes. I got error after first 3 iterations using your code. Then after some tinkering(not in code) it worked perfectly. I want to learn more about webscraping in general. I hope you don't mind connecting on linkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/yash-agarwal-806222127/

Comment: sent connection request :)